# Getting User Attributes of a Logged in Liferay user

Tags: jsp, liferay, query-string, zimbra

How do I get the email ID of a logged in Liferay user (from within a portlet) ?

I referred to [this](http://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/%5bhowto%5d-personalization-getting-current-user-attributes) link but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the following code in your JSP:

<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>

<%= user.getDisplayEmailAddress() %>